# SelectOption not setting String

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm currently experiencing a strange problem with using a SelectOption list to set a String when I call a method.

Here is my VF code:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="project">
  <form role="form">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="projectNameToUpdate">Project</label>
          <apex:selectList id="projectNameToUpdate" styleClass="form-control" title="projectNameToUpdate" value="{!selectedProject}" size="1">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!DivisionList}" />
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="project" />
          </apex:selectList>
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="doUpdateProject();" />
    </form>
    <apex:actionRegion rendered="true">
      <a href="#" onclick="alert ('{!selectedProject}');">Test</a>
      <p>Your info</p>
    <apex:actionRegion>
  </apex:outputPanel>
```

And my Apex code:

```
public String projectToUpdate;
public String selectedProject { get; set { selectedProject = value; }

public List<SelectOption> getDivisionList() {
    List<SelectOption> projectList = new List<SelectOption>();
    projectList.add(new SelectOption('', ''));

    for (ts2__Project_Job__c p : [SELECT Name FROM ts2__Project_Job__c WHERE ts2__Project_Manager__c = :user AND Project_Status__c != 'Completed'])
        projectList.add(new SelectOption(p.Name, p.Name));

    return projectList;
}
```

What's strange here is then when I use this SelectOption list and click a value, it doesn't set the variable **unless** I click that option twice. For some reason, it's completely ignoring the first click.

Hopefully I've asked this question correctly! Any ideas/help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks!